# How is the maximum number of workers in PyTorch DataLoader decided if there are 2 CPUs in a node?

Tags: pytorch, cpu, pytorch-dataloader

I was trying to run an autoencoder using an HPC node that had 2 CPUs and each of them had 20 cores (so 40 CPUs per node). When using `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`, I specified `num_workers` as 40 instead of 20 since I thought that there were 40 CPU cores available.

However, I got the following warning:

```
/jet/home/wehs7661/.conda/envs/diffnets/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:481: UserWarning: This `DataLoader` will create 40 worker processes in total. Our suggested max number of worker in current system is 20, which is smaller than what this DataLoader is going to create. Please be aware that excessive worker creation might get DataLoader running slow or even freeze, lower the worker number to avoid potential slowness/freeze if necessary.
  cpuset_checked))
```

This kind of confused me since I thought that the maximum number of workers should be 40 instead of 20. I'm wondering how the maximum number of workers is decided in `DataLoader` and if I should change `num_workers` to 20 even if I actually have 40 cores.

Answer (score -5):

The DataLoader class in PyTorch that helps us to load and iterate over elements in a dataset is the class that is used for DataLoader in the `torch.utils.data` module. DataLoader. It uses arguments as follow:

```
DataLoader(
    dataset,
    batch_size=1,
    shuffle=False,
    num_workers='',
    collate_fn=None,
    pin_memory=False,
 )
```

So if you are seeking to work with main processor to load your data when needed, set
`num_workers=0`. you will get out of the the problem as soon as you did it!